# How to stop any process of jQuery to change document.location

Tags: jquery, ajax, abort

For a little project, I have a page where I realize one long-time request (2 minutes) with 1ms timeout (just need to launch the process async and I don't need any backup), and some AJAX calls every 5 seconds.

I want to do a button to cancel all AJAX calls, and change the document.location.

I've used the xhrPool script trying to cancel all AJAX calls, and then, I call the document.location line. But, when I click on the button, the script seems to be blocked by some AJAX calls pending, and the user (me) need to wait about 20-30s, too loooong.

There's my script:

```
$.xhrPool = [];
$.xhrPool.abortAll = function() {
    $(this).each(function(idx, jqXHR) {
        jqXHR.abort();
    });
    $.xhrPool = [];
};

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
        $.xhrPool.push(jqXHR);
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR) {
        var index = $.xhrPool.indexOf(jqXHR);
        if (index > -1) {
            $.xhrPool.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});

function toTime(c) {
    var str = '';
    if (c > 59) {
        str = Math.floor(c/60) + 'm ';
        c %= 60;
    }
    if (c > 0)
        str = str + c + 's';
    return str;
}

function updateProgress() {
    $('.progress .bar').animate({
        width: count*4
    }, {duration:1000, easing: 'linear'});
    $('.progress .bar').html(toTime(count));
}

function timer() {
    updateProgress();
    if (count > 0) {
        if ((count % 5) == 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/?act=verifyStatus',
                timeout: 5000
            }).done(function(data){
            if (data == 'OK')
                document.location = '/?act=found';
            });
        }
    } else {
        document.location = '/?act=nodelivers';
    }
    count--;
    setTimeout('timer()', 1000);
}

$(function(){
    $('.cancel').click(function(){
        $.xhrPool.abortAll();
        document.location = '/?act=form';
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '/?act=doContact',
        timeout: 1
    });
    timer();
});
```

Thanks by advance

Comment: If you're leaving the page, why bother with the cancel?

Comment: AJAX calls itself will not prevent browser from page reload and there is no need to stop them before you leave page. Do you use session in your long running request? Possibly you should wait because of session being blocked by that request and server just place your next request into a queue waiting for session being released

Comment: Sorry I dont'n understand because in your cancel.click you change the document location and later call timer() which in turn call itself each 1s.

Comment: So, I'll explain the system: My long process time limit is set to 0 (unlimited) and ignore_user_abort(true). He modify an entry in the DB every 20 seconds, and can be interrupted by an external call, no problem with that.

But, the user must can cancel the process, going to the /?act=form. But when I click on this link, the load of the new page is very very long, like if he's waiting the end of the last AJAX call ...

Understood ? ^^'

Thanks by advance !

Comment: FAngel: Yes, I use the session to pass all parameters, there's about 40 params ... But I don't want to reset the session, for the user experience :/

Answer (score 0):

Just add a button that sets a global variable status to 'run' or 'stop' and before every call, check the status of that variable ? Then redirect if needed.

Comment: I'll try that solution :) It seems legit ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Like said by FAngel, the first long process was blocking other requests !

So, in this process, I just added session_write_close(); after the last session access, and all works fine now !

Thanks !